# What used EBCDIC code pages 1 thru 5?

Tags: character-sets, ebcdic

For US English, the most commonly used EBCDIC code page is 37, which is one of the CECP code pages (Country Extended Code Page). The old IBM [globalisation database](http://ftpmirror.your.org/pub/misc/ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP00037.txt) has a 1986 copyright date for code page 37, although the dates in that database are [not entirely accurate](https://www.os2museum.com/wp/where-did-cp852-come-from/). There are also other EBCDIC code pages sometimes used instead, most notably 1047.

My question, however, is about the pre-CECP US English EBCDIC code pages which predated code page 37 – 1 thru 5. Who used each of them? When were they each introduced? Why are there five of them? What IBM software actually supported them?

There is very little information about them in official IBM sources, all I've been able to find is [old pages on the IBM i globalisation website](https://web.archive.org/web/20120716195651/http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/globalization/codepages.html):

- [USA WP, Original (00001)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121105054/http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00001z.pdf)
- [USA (00002)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121104138/http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00002z.pdf)
- [USA, Accounting, Version A (00003)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121110321/http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00003z.pdf)
- [United States (00004)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121110233/http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00004z.pdf)
- [United States (00005)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121104307/http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00005z.pdf)

(I got the above archived links from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#EBCDIC-based_code_pages) and [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Character_Encodings/Code_Tables/EBCDIC/EBCDIC_001).)

Comment: IIRC 001 was meant to allow import and handling of text files (letters) from office systems, while 003 was the generic base page for compatibility with old style accounting machinery (classic electro-mechanical punch card stuff) it should be the one with the least characters..